# Bootstrap image thumbnail are difference size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm work on bootstrap project and I try to put uploading image to set grid view, but uploading image are not same size 4 images are difference size, I put the image `width` and `height` but its not working image are  sketching and not display full image any one know how to fix that issue

Thanks
,

```css
/*image*/
.thumbnail{
  width: 164px;
  height: 164px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                  <div class="row display-flex">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://www.averagejoes.co.uk/averagejoes.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ihotel-taiwan-hotel-gaming-esports-video-games-1.jpg"  alt="" class="avatar">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://www.averagejoes.co.uk/averagejoes.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ihotel-taiwan-hotel-gaming-esports-video-games-1.jpg" alt="" class="avatar">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://exp.cdn-hotels.com/hotels/2000000/1900000/1897400/1897350/7180d426_z.jpg" alt="" class="avatar">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://www.averagejoes.co.uk/averagejoes.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ihotel-taiwan-hotel-gaming-esports-video-games-1.jpg" alt="" class="avatar">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by _sketching_. Maybe try `height: 100%;` on `img`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class `img-fluid` on image .

Like this

`<img src="https://www.averagejoes.co.uk/averagejoes.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ihotel-taiwan-hotel-gaming-esports-video-games-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">`

**or** 
update the following css :

```
.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add Following Css to the code **object-fit: cover;** May Help You

```
.thumbnail
{
      width: 164px;
      height: 164px;
      overflow: hidden;
       margin: auto;
}
.thumbnail img {
    width: 164px;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please see edited answer. Had you tried using thumbnail height

Answer (score 0):

To make images fit in the containing div, add the class `img-fluid` to them. This wil give them a `width: 100%; height: auto;`.

This won't give them all the same height, as they have different sizes/aspect ratios.

```css
/*image*/
.thumbnail{
  width: 164px;
  height: 164px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                  <div class="row display-flex">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://www.averagejoes.co.uk/averagejoes.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ihotel-taiwan-hotel-gaming-esports-video-games-1.jpg"  alt="" class="img-fluid avatar">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://www.averagejoes.co.uk/averagejoes.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ihotel-taiwan-hotel-gaming-esports-video-games-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid avatar">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://exp.cdn-hotels.com/hotels/2000000/1900000/1897400/1897350/7180d426_z.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid avatar">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://www.averagejoes.co.uk/averagejoes.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ihotel-taiwan-hotel-gaming-esports-video-games-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid avatar">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Hello Sir, look at your 3rd image  not a same size ,